# How to resolve Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder error?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages

Having a "duh" moment trying to implement a new content page

Here's the structure

```
Master Page
---- Nested Master Page
-------- Nested Master's Content Page
```

Mark up:

**Master Page**

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="bodyContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**Nested Master Page**

```
MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Administrator.Master"
<asp:Content ID="Content2" CotentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent" runat="server">
 </asp:Content>
```

**Nested Master's Content Page**

```
MasterPageFile="~/Views/Intervention/InterventionMaster.master"
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="myContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content2">
 </asp:Content>
```

Receive error:

> Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'Content2' in the master page
>   '/Views/Intervention/InterventionMaster.master', verify content
>   control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: is it possible that your content-page is referring to the outer-most master page instead of the nested one?

Comment: First off, you're nesting master pages. What does this buy you? Most likely you've got the wrong master definition at the top of your aspx page. Can you show us the MasterPageFile directive of the Nested Content page?

Comment: @n8wrl - Not sure how, since I have this in the content page: MasterPageFile="~/Views/Intervention/InterventionMaster.master

Comment: @subt13: According to the documentation the nested content page needs to reference the nested master rather than the parent. I'd look at this for the first point of debugging.

Comment: @JoelEtherton - nested master pages saves me from writing a lot of redundant markup

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't have `ContentPlaceHolder` with `ID = "Content2"`. You have only content with such ID. Put another placeholder inside of content with `ID="Content2"` and then connect with the page content.

**Master Page**

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="bodyContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**Nested Master Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="nestedContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </asp:Content>
```

**Nested Master's Content Page**

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="myContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="nestedContent">
 </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Hello there is a syntax error in the nested master page section: CotentPlaceHolderID should be ContentPlaceHolderID

Answer (score 2):

*A dirty-quick* solution would be to bypass the **Nested Master Page**
from the Nested Master's Content Page

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Master.MasterPageFile = "~/Whatever.Master";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use** `ID="MainContent"`

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeone was close, try using

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```